# Does Google.Protobuf support .NET Core?

Tags: uwp, .net-core, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-csharp-port

I know from looking at the [Google.Protobuf Git](https://github.com/google/protobuf) that there are some comments about .NET Core support but when I get a copy of the source code from Git the Google.Protobuf Project has .NetFramework 4.5 listed in the Dependencies along with .NetStandard 1.0.

On the Google.Protobuf Git Depot in the [csharp folder](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/csharp) there are some further comments about .NET Core support.

Also by going through the Issues Tracker on the attached to the Depot I came across this [thread](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2549) from about a year back about getting Google.Protobuf to play nice with .NET Core.

Can anyone give me a definitive answer on whether or not Google.Protobuf supports .NET Core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Google.Protobuf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf/) targets .NET 4.5 *and* netstandard1.0. It's important to understand that when multiple frameworks are listed in terms of dependencies, that just means that the package uses multi-targeting to support multiple frameworks.

Given that UWP now supports netstandard2.0, it should definitely work with a netstandard1.0 library.

It's possible that reflection (including JSON support) won't work as it requires both regular reflection and (currently) expression tree compilation - but for simple serialization and deserialization it should be absolutely fine.